# Kibana does not show fields from grok filter in filebeat

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

I have log file with apache logs that i want to show in Kibana.
The logs start with IP. I have debuged my pattern and it passes.
I'm trying to add fields in the beats input configuration file, but are not show in Kibana even after refresh of the fields. 
Here is the configuration file

```
filter {
  if[type] == "apache" {
    grok {
      match => { "message" => "%{HOST:log_host}%{GREEDYDATA:remaining}" }
      add_field => { "testip" => "%{log_host}" }
      add_field => { "data_left" => "%{remaining}" }
    }
  }
...
```

Just to add that I have restarted all the services: logstash, elasticsearch, kibana after the new configuration.

Comment: FYI, restarting the non-Logstash services is unnecessary for this kind of change.

Answer (score 1):

The issue could be that your `grok` pattern is using too rigid of patterns.

- Chances are that `HOST` should be `IPORHOST` based on your `test_ip` field's name.

Assuming that the data is actually coming in with the type defined as `apache`, then it should be:

```
filter {
  if [type] == "apache" {
    grok {
      match => {
        message => "%{IPORHOST:log_host}%{GREEDYDATA:remaining}"
      }
      add_field => {
        testip => "%{log_host}"
        data_left => "%{remaining}"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Having said that, your usage of `add_field` is completely unnecessary. The `grok` pattern itself is creating two fields: `log_host` and `remaining`, so there's no need to define extra fields called `testip` and `data_left`.

Perhaps even more usefully, you don't need to craft your own Apache web log `grok` pattern. [The `COMBINEDAPACHELOG` pattern already exists](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-patterns-core/blob/master/patterns/grok-patterns#L95), which gives all of the standard fields automatically.

```
filter {
  if [type] == "apache" {
    grok {
      match => { "message" => "%{COMBINEDAPACHELOG}" }
    }
    # Set @timestamp to the log's time and drop the unneeded timestamp
    date {
      match => [ "timestamp" , "dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss Z" ]
      remove_field => "timestamp"
    }
  }
}
```

You can see this in [a more complete example in the Logstash documentation here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/config-examples.html).

Comment: I have run a test wit %{GREEDYDATA:remaining} only. and it still seems not to be working.Here is the JSON format of the output in Kibana:

`"_source": {
    "message": "/valid message here/",
    "@version": "1",
    "@timestamp": "2016-06-21T09:19:12.770Z",
    "offset": 406600,
    "beat": {
      "hostname": "/name/",
      "name": "/name/"
    },` 
`remaining` field is nowhere to be found.

Comment: My favorite way to debug Logstash is to put your message into a text file, then `cat` it into Logstash: `cat myfile.txt | bin/logstash -f myconf.conf`. For that I use `stdin` input and `stdout` output. My guess is that your `type` is not matching, so it's not even running. An easy test is to remove the type check and see what happens (probably a grok parse failure).

Comment: That was a step forward. However, now i use only %{IPORHOST} to get the ip field, but in the ouput i get exactly what is in the input.

Comment: What is the output if you use `output { stdout { codec => rubydebug } }`? This will spit out the entire event, including any meta fields.